# bash: Convert human readable time to epoch in large files

Tags: bash, epoch

I have huge csv files (>50 GB) that have the following columns:-

"time", "data column"

The time column has data like "2015-07-10 00:17:45.000 GMT". I wish to convert the time column to reflect the equivalent epoch time instead of the human readable form.

What can be the fastest way to do this without creating another file? (This csv file is originally the output of a python script).

Comment: Doing this in place would not be any faster (and is significantly more complicated). If you have the python script, you might find it easier to tweak it to output seconds since epoch instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date --date="2015-07-10 00:17:45.000 GMT" '+%s'
```

will print

```
1436487465
```

You can use cut to do the rest:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
  timefield=$(echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d, | tr -d '"')
  epochal=$(date --date="$timefield" '+%s')
  restofline=$(echo "$line" | cut -f2- -d,)
  echo "$epochal,$restofline"
done <$1
```

To use the above script just save it to a file, chmod it executable, and run it supplying the filename to read as the first argument.

So with inp.tst:

```
"2015-07-10 00:17:45.000 GMT","misc data","blah"
"2015-07-10 00:18:45.000 GMT","more data","misc"
```

You can use:

```
./fixtimes.sh inp.tst
```

to get

```
1436487465,"misc data","blah"
1436487525,"more data","misc"
```